# Java code, ASCII art, switch statements/structure, enter a character and then print it on the screen

Tags: java, switch-statement, ascii-art

This is what I am asked of in my lab:

> 1. Create a new class called ASCIIArt inside of your lab 4 project.
>    2. Before getting started, I want you to decide on 5 characters you would like to turn into
>    ASCII art. Choose any 5 you can find on the keyboard (excluding the examples below and function keys like Enter, Backspace, F1, Esc...) and think about how you can make them into ASCII art.
>    3. Back to the code, tell the user what characters you can turn into art for them, and then ask the user what character they would like to see turned into ASCII Art.
>    4. Using a switch statement/structure, you should implement the large versions of all 5 characters you have chosen.
>    5. If the user enters in an invalid character (not one of the 5 you choose) tell them that they made an invalid choice (hint: use the default case in your switch statement)
>    6. Make sure you have comments throughout your program (including your header comment at the beginning of your program).

Here is what I have

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ASCIIArt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Chose a letter to print: E, T, F, Z, I.");
        int ASCIIArt = keyboard.nextInt();
        switch (ASCIIArt) {
            case 'E': {
                System.out.println("*****");
                System.out.println("*    ");
                System.out.println("*****");
                System.out.println("*    ");
                System.out.println("*****");
                break;
            }
            case 'T': {
                System.out.println("*****");
                System.out.println("  *  ");
                System.out.println("  *  ");
                System.out.println("  *  ");
                System.out.println("  *  ");
                break;
            }
            case 'F': {
                System.out.println("*****");
                System.out.println("*    ");
                System.out.println("*****");
                System.out.println("*    ");
                System.out.println("*    ");
                break;
            }
            case 'Z': {
                System.out.println("*****");
                System.out.println("   * ");
                System.out.println("  *  ");
                System.out.println(" *   ");
                System.out.println("*****");
                break;
            }
            case 'I': {
                System.out.println("*****");
                System.out.println("  *  ");
                System.out.println("  *  ");
                System.out.println("  *  ");
                System.out.println("*****");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where did I messed up and somehow I cannot add default meaning at the end. ECLIPSE says its undefined.

Comment: I don't think `int ASCIIArt = keyboard.nextInt();` is what you want. Try something like `keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0)`. Also, by "default meaning at the end" do you mean you cannot add the `default` case?

Comment: Yes, whenever i try to add it, my ECLIPSE software do not recognize it "syntax error on token" thats what it says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ASCIIArt {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        while (true)
        {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Chose a letter to print: E, T, F, Z, I.");

            String asciiString = keyboard.next();

            switch (asciiString.charAt(0)) {

                case 'E': {
                    System.out.println("*****");
                    System.out.println("*    ");
                    System.out.println("*****");
                    System.out.println("*    ");
                    System.out.println("*****");
                    break;
                }
                case 'T': {
                    System.out.println("*****");
                    System.out.println("  *  ");
                    System.out.println("  *  ");
                    System.out.println("  *  ");
                    System.out.println("  *  ");
                    break;
                }
                case 'F': {
                    System.out.println("*****");
                    System.out.println("*    ");
                    System.out.println("*****");
                    System.out.println("*    ");
                    System.out.println("*    ");
                    break;
                }
                case 'Z': {
                    System.out.println("*****");
                    System.out.println("   * ");
                    System.out.println("  *  ");
                    System.out.println(" *   ");
                    System.out.println("*****");
                    break;
                }
                case 'I': {
                    System.out.println("*****");
                    System.out.println("  *  ");
                    System.out.println("  *  ");
                    System.out.println("  *  ");
                    System.out.println("*****");
                    break;  
                }
                default:
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid char - press anykey");
                    System.in.read();                       
                }       
            }  
        }

    }

    public static void functionDumpText() throws IOException
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: bear in mind this application won't stop until you terminate it the hard way.

Comment: This is the perfect answer i was looking for. Ian sorry i couldn't explain in the beginning that the thing i needed was a loop. Thank you tho

Comment: anyway I can contact you directly? i have another question and you seem to be a reliable source

Comment: Not directly. No but i'll try to keep a close eye on your questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ASCIIArt {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        functionDumpText();
    }

    public static void functionDumpText() throws IOException
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Chose a letter to print: E, T, F, Z, I.");

        String asciiString = keyboard.next();

        switch (asciiString.charAt(0)) {

            case 'E': {
                System.out.println("*****");
                System.out.println("*    ");
                System.out.println("*****");
                System.out.println("*    ");
                System.out.println("*****");
                break;
            }
            case 'T': {
                System.out.println("*****");
                System.out.println("  *  ");
                System.out.println("  *  ");
                System.out.println("  *  ");
                System.out.println("  *  ");
                break;
            }
            case 'F': {
                System.out.println("*****");
                System.out.println("*    ");
                System.out.println("*****");
                System.out.println("*    ");
                System.out.println("*    ");
                break;
            }
            case 'Z': {
                System.out.println("*****");
                System.out.println("   * ");
                System.out.println("  *  ");
                System.out.println(" *   ");
                System.out.println("*****");
                break;
            }
            case 'I': {
                System.out.println("*****");
                System.out.println("  *  ");
                System.out.println("  *  ");
                System.out.println("  *  ");
                System.out.println("*****");
                break;  
            }
            default:
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid char - press anykey");
                System.in.read();

                functionDumpText();
            }       
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is functionDumpText?

Comment: And what is IO.exception? i am really new to java, would be nice if you add some //comments

Comment: functionDumpText is a container for all the actions you did in the main entry point of your application. 

The reason i did this is b/c of when a user enters a wrong entry how did you intend go back.

Comment: It might be handy that you look into some tutorials on the internet and first get a grasp on programming. I get the feeling that you want to 'build a house without the bricks'

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/

Comment: Also try to run through the application by stepping through it. (debug mode) and see what happens.

Comment: Chose a letter to print: E, T, F, Z, I.
a
Invalid char - press anykey

Chose a letter to print: E, T, F, Z, I.
E
*****
*    
*****
*    
*****

Comment: Then, how do we make it without that function?

Comment: The problem lies in circularity.
For example try to understand this:

1,2,3 at the end of 3 i want to go back to 1.....

Same as with the application 1 is the function
2 is the execution of the switch case statement
3. something went wrong i want to go back to 1.